# react router changes the URL, but the component is not rendered

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a component that consumes an API and renders a list. Each list item has a custom link to redirect to it's page.

I'm trying to make this route getting the URL params, to show the other component.

But despite the URL changes, the other component is never rendered when I click the list item. But the funny thing is that if I type the URL manually, it renders.

Here goes my code:

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

// import Routes from "./routes";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import GlobalStyle from "./styles/global";

import Main from "./pages/Main";
import Hero from "./pages/Hero";
import Favorites from "./pages/Favorites";

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <GlobalStyle />
    <Navbar />
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/favorites">Favoritos</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <Switch>
      {/* <Main path="/hero/:heroId" component={Hero} /> */}
      <Route path="/hero" component={Hero} />
      <Route path="/favorites" component={Favorites} />
      <Route path="/" exact component={Main} />

      {/* <Route path="/hero" render={props => <Hero {...props} />} /> */}
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);
export default App;
```

**Main.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import api from "../../services/api";
import md5 from "js-md5";

import { SearchBar, SearchInput, SearchButton, Wrapper } from "./styles";

import Card from "../../components/Card";

export default class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      heroes: [],
      search: ""
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadHeroes();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.searc !== this.state.search) {
      this.loadHeroes();
    }
  }

  loadHeroes = async () => {
    const PUBLIC_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC;
    const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_PRIVATE;
    const timestamp = Number(new Date());
    const hash = md5.create();
    hash.update(timestamp + PRIVATE_KEY + PUBLIC_KEY);

    if (this.state.search === "") {
      await api
        .get(`/characters?ts=${timestamp}&apikey=${PUBLIC_KEY}&hash=${hash}`)
        .then(response =>
          this.setState({ heroes: response.data.data.results })
        );
    } else {
      await api
        .get(
          `/characters?nameStartsWith=${this.state.search}&ts=${timestamp}&apikey=${PUBLIC_KEY}&hash=${hash}`
        )
        .then(response =>
          this.setState({ heroes: response.data.data.results })
        );
    }
  };

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ search: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log("State do search: ", this.state.search);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    const { heroes } = this.state;

    let filteredHeroes = heroes.filter(
      hero => hero.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search) !== -1
    );

    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Buscar
            <SearchInput
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              type="search"
              value={this.state.search}
            />
          </label>
          <SearchButton type="submit" value="Enviar" />
        </SearchBar>

        <Router>
          <Wrapper>
            {filteredHeroes.map(hero => {
              return (
                <Link
                  to={`hero?q=${hero.id}`}
                  style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}
                  key={hero.id}
                >
                  <Card name={hero.name} thumbnail={hero.thumbnail} />
                </Link>
              );
            })}
          </Wrapper>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Hero.js**

```
import React from "react";

const Hero = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.name}</h1>

      <article>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima
          accusamus ducimus qui amet quis? Non rerum consequuntur soluta,
          voluptatum blanditiis explicabo, laudantium architecto distinctio enim
          aliquid placeat, quaerat voluptas totam!
        </p>
      </article>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Hero;
```

Comment: try ```exact``` prop of ```<Route/>``` component

Comment: @Marcelo Melo keep <Route path="/" exact component={Main} /> as first route.

Comment: @VahidAkhtar
I've just made it... but didn't solve the problem

Comment: @HardikChaudhary I tried, but didn't work too...

Comment: See this working demo https://codepen.io/hardik-chaudhary/pen/QoXYwZ?editors=1010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make following changes in your code !

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

// import Routes from "./routes";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import GlobalStyle from "./styles/global";

import Main from "./pages/Main";
import Hero from "./pages/Hero";
import Favorites from "./pages/Favorites";

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <GlobalStyle />
    <Navbar />
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/favorites">Favoritos</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Main} />
      <Route path="/hero" exact component={Hero} />
      <Route path="/favorites" exact component={Favorites} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);
export default App;
```

**Main.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import api from "../../services/api";
import md5 from "js-md5";

import { SearchBar, SearchInput, SearchButton, Wrapper } from "./styles";

import Card from "../../components/Card";

export default class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      heroes: [],
      search: ""
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadHeroes();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.searc !== this.state.search) {
      this.loadHeroes();
    }
  }

  loadHeroes = async () => {
    const PUBLIC_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC;
    const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_PRIVATE;
    const timestamp = Number(new Date());
    const hash = md5.create();
    hash.update(timestamp + PRIVATE_KEY + PUBLIC_KEY);

    if (this.state.search === "") {
      await api
        .get(`/characters?ts=${timestamp}&apikey=${PUBLIC_KEY}&hash=${hash}`)
        .then(response =>
          this.setState({ heroes: response.data.data.results })
        );
    } else {
      await api
        .get(
          `/characters?nameStartsWith=${this.state.search}&ts=${timestamp}&apikey=${PUBLIC_KEY}&hash=${hash}`
        )
        .then(response =>
          this.setState({ heroes: response.data.data.results })
        );
    }
  };

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ search: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log("State do search: ", this.state.search);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    const { heroes } = this.state;

    let filteredHeroes = heroes.filter(
      hero => hero.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search) !== -1
    );

    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Buscar
            <SearchInput
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              type="search"
              value={this.state.search}
            />
          </label>
          <SearchButton type="submit" value="Enviar" />
        </SearchBar>
          <Wrapper>
            {filteredHeroes.map(hero => {
              return (
                <Link
                  to={`/hero?q=${hero.id}`}
                  style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}
                  key={hero.id}
                >
                  <Card name={hero.name} thumbnail={hero.thumbnail} />
                </Link>
              );
            })}
          </Wrapper>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and no need to change in Herocomponent.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately it's still not working

The result is still  the same: the URL changes in the browser, but the component is not rendered, unless I refresh the browser...

Do you have another tip?

Comment: [link](https://repl.it/repls/ActiveSmallLaw) working example of rendering component using react router.

Comment: Now it worked!!!

The only thing here now is that when the Hero component is rendered, I can't get the props I've got from the api and the console shows

`Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in Main (created by Context.Consumer)`

Answer (score 0):

you need to make two changes

in you Main.js

```
                <Link
                  to={`hero/${hero.id}`}
                  style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}
                  key={hero.id}
                >
                  <Card name={hero.name} thumbnail={hero.thumbnail} />
                </Link>
```

and in your routes, add another route or change existing to

```
<Route path="/hero/:heroId" component={Hero} />
```

Hope this would help. Extract your heroID using

```
 props.match.params.heroId
```

Comment: Thanks for your help... but unfortunately it still not working... The only thing I got was the **heroId**, by the `props.match.params.heroId` but the component is still not rendering when I click in a list item

Comment: Can you make jsfiddle?

Comment: @MarceloMelo is there any error on screen or console?